# Как сделать ЧПУ без записей в .htaccess?

Tags: php

Как сделать ЧПУ без записей в .htaccess на PHP?
Такое реализовано в WordPress, а вот как я не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант вот так :

запрос будет таким : **mysite.zone/?/show_page/name/number**

```
<?php

preg_match_all('#\/([a-z0-9_]*)#', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $index_qs);

echo $index_qs[1][0];//show_page
echo $index_qs[1][1];//name
echo $index_qs[1][2];//number

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Разбирать `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Правда, совсем без .htaccess не получится, нужно как минимум обработчик 404 туда вписать.

Comment: А как разобрать запрос site.com/user/1234 ?  
Без записи в htaccess или httpd.conf никак.  
Хотя можно делать ЧПУ вида site.com/?user/1234 или site.com/#user/1234, но это моветон.

Comment: Как? Очень просто (ну и код привожу не самый интеллектуальный, просто как пример):

    $uri_parts = split( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    array_shift($uri_parts);
    if( $uri_parts[0] == 'user' )
    {
    // ID содержится в $uri_parts[1]
    }
    elseif( $uri_parts[0] == 'ляля' )
    {
    // ...
    }

Comment: Так скрипт с каким именем это выполняет? При запросе site.com/user/1234/ сервер будет пытаться найти /1234/index.php, а не найдя сгенерирует 404.  
Если задать свой обработчик 404, который будет вместо страницы с ошибкой выдавать контент, то Вы получите много веселостей при индексации сайта поисковыми системами и когда захотите отправить странице post-запрос.  
Так что без записей в htaccess ЧПУ можно сделать только аналогичными записями в httpd.conf

Comment: Я вообще-то отвечал на заданный вопрос, а не рассуждал на смежные темы :)